# Entity Framework update DB problem when use AutoDetectChangesEnabled=false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I use Entity Framework and stored procedures.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>().MapToStoredProcedures();
```

I used Insert update and delete without any problem.but for some purpose I want to use `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`

After that entity doesn't work anymore and nothing changes in the database after `SaveChanges`. But when I comment `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` or set it to true, it works fine.

This is my code: I read from Excel and import into database:

```
dt = exc.ReadExcel(address, ".xlsx");

using (var db = new Context())
{
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

    for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());

        var thisChah = db.MyModel.Find(id);

        if (thisChah == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        thisChah.f1 = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        thisChah.f2 = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
        thisChah.f3 = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
        thisChah.f4 = dt.Rows[i][4].ToString();
        thisChah.f5 = dt.Rows[i][5].ToString();
        thisChah.f6 = dt.Rows[i][6].ToString();
        thisChah.f7 = dt.Rows[i][7].ToString();

        LogsAnyThing("row " + i + "- OK ");

        if(i % 50 == 0)
        {
            int result = db.SaveChanges();

            if (result > 0)
            {
                LogsAnyThing("row " + i + "- Added ");
            }
        }
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have turned off AutoDetectChanges , you need to explicitly tell context to look for any changes before attempting to call SaveChanges(). You can do this by adding this statement - `db.ChangeTracker.DetectChange()` before call to db.SaveChanges(). Without this context is not aware that any changes has been done to the model. 
You can read more @https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/auto-detect-changes

Comment: I used this method because wanna insert 100K excel row do db with entity and in took very long time and entity is slowly !!. is `db.ChangeTracker.DetectChange()` good for this after savechanges ?

Comment: If you want to add multiple rows, you can take a look at [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange(v=vs.113).aspx)  method. Performance can be better with AddRange compared to adding row one by one.

Comment: yes AddRange is good for Insert.what is your opinion about Update ?

Comment: EF doesn't support batch update out of the box and you will have to use some third party library that can batch all update statement together and send it once to the db server to execute. You should take a look at [EF Plus library](https://entityframework-plus.net/?z=ef-extended)..

Comment: what a nice Library. Interesting . Thanks